# Нужно ли ставить запятую в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Она играла на нервах(,) и на камеру.

Answer (score 1):

Это тема однородные члены: играла (на чём?) на нервах и на камеру.
Возможны варианты:

1. Она играла на нервах и на камеру.
2. Она играла на нервах, и на камеру.

В первом случае “и на нервах входит” входит в основное сообщение, а во втором носит присоединительный характер, то есть  вносит в основное сообщение дополнительное сведение/замечание.